# Failed to execute OCDIIndexStart() Routine while using SDO_WITHIN_DISTANCE

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-spatial

I am trying to find the points that lie within a distance of 5 km from a point used in query.
[Table Description and Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKq6E.jpg)
[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJTbv.jpg)
The tables contain 2D point data with both tables containing **coordis** as the SDO_GEOMETRY type column. Any help on the error please? I am using Oracle Spatial for Oracle 11g. This is my first time experience with Oracle Spatial. So, I might be making some very silly mistakes without being aware about it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you created the spatial index on your table? The message suggests that no. 
`SDO_WITHIN_DISTANCE` requires index.

> Uses the spatial index to identify the set of spatial objects that are
>   within some specified distance of a given object, such as an area of
>   interest or point of interest.

`OCDInexStart` method is part of [`ODCIIndex Interface`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28425/dom_idx.htm). And this method is executed always when Oracle wants to use domain index.

Comment: Yes I have have created the spatial index for SDO_GEOMETRY column coordis of the table. I used: CREATE INDEX vwplots_table1_spatial_idx on vwplots_table1(coordis)
INDEXTYPE IS MDSYS.SPATIAL_INDEX;

Comment: Please update your question, add all structures, sample dataset, and query.

Comment: I have included a picture of table description and the data. Please check it out.

Comment: Look at this post. [why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) Explanation why images are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because you compare the output of the operator to the string 'true'. That should be upper-case 'TRUE'.

I know, I know. It looks silly. But it is like that. Also you cannot compare to FALSE (or false). But you can compare to <> 'TRUE'.

Comment: And BTW as already stated. Never include images of screen captures. Copy the screen content as text and include that.